# How can you run multiple docker containers from your computer, and have each use a different IP (using a VPN)?

Tags: docker, ip, vpn

I'm trying to understand how this would conceptually work, and also put it into use.

I'm on a Mac running OS 10.11.X, using a Private Internet Access VPN. I'm trying to run multiple (ideally 3-4) docker containers and tell them all to use separate IPs for their connection. I'm not sure how I could even split different IPs from PIA VPN to begin with, then figure out the docker side.

Or do I have the picture wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS is running on the laptop?

Comment: edited to add Mac OS X 10.11.X, thanks!

Comment: Linux would have been a better answer :)  I would get the info from your VPN provider on how they will support multiple IP's first.  Running Docker on virtualbox will complicate networking setup. You might get more response on [unix/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) once you have that info too as this isn't about the programming side of things.